# How can I customize the GTK desktop title bar?

Tags: unity, gtk, window-decoration

How can I customize the GTK title bar for the Gnome/Unity desktop, in Ubuntu 22.04?

I have several VMs running under VirtualBox, all in fullscreen mode (which shouldn't be significant) and I want to see which VM I'm using at the top of the screen, along with the time.

Note that I am not talking about the title bars of application windows, just the one that runs full width at the very top,

Please bear with me; I might be using the wrong terms.  I'm running stock Ubuntu 22.04 with no modifications, and using whatever the default GUI desktop is.  I don't know all the codenames.

NOTE: I have Wayland disabled.  I have no use for a window manager that doesn't allow positioning windows via the `geometry` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want are gnome extensions. You can find them [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/). I use the [extension manager](https://github.com/mjakeman/extension-manager) myself to install them in one click.

Are you looking for [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6272/add-custom-text-to-workspace-indicators/)?

Comment: Thanks, the PRATAP-KUMAR/add-custom-text-to-workspace-indicators extension does exactly what I want (and more) but seems to require Wayland (and I've added that I disabled Wayland in the question.)

Comment: Actually, it was a GNOME version incompatibility, but another extension by the same author, https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4405/replace-activities-text/ works great.